# Setting up mutt for Gmail

Tags: email, gmail, mutt

I am trying to set up mutt for Gmail. I am following [Crunchbang wiki instructions](https://web.archive.org/web/20130328173703/http://www.crunchbanglinux.org/wiki/howto/howto_setup_mutt_with_gmail_imap), however, after putting

```
set from = "yourusername@gmail.com"
set realname = "Your Real Name"

set imap_user = "yourusername@gmail.com"
set imap_pass = "yourpassword"
```

(with my details, of course), I get

```
$ mutt
Error in $HOME/.muttrc, line 12: imap_user: unknown variable
Error in $HOME/.muttrc, line 13: imap_pass: unknown variable
source: errors in $HOME/.muttrc
Press any key to continue...
```

If I try to send an email, it doesn't work because instead of IMAP, it tries to send email directly from my localhost's mail system. Mutt says it is version Mutt 1.4.2.3i.

**Update:**

So I downloaded mutt-devel on Macports, which is 1.5:

```
$ mutt -v
Mutt 1.5.21 (2010-09-15)
Copyright (C) 1996-2009 Michael R. Elkins and others.
Mutt comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY; for details type `mutt -vv'.
Mutt is free software, and you are welcome to redistribute it
under certain conditions; type `mutt -vv' for details.

System: Darwin 11.3.0 (x86_64)
ncurses: ncurses 5.9.20110404 (compiled with 5.9)
libiconv: 1.14
libidn: 1.22 (compiled with 1.22)
Compile options:
-DOMAIN
-DEBUG
-HOMESPOOL  +USE_SETGID  +USE_DOTLOCK  +DL_STANDALONE  +USE_FCNTL  -USE_FLOCK   
+USE_POP  +USE_IMAP  -USE_SMTP  
-USE_SSL_OPENSSL  -USE_SSL_GNUTLS  -USE_SASL  -USE_GSS  +HAVE_GETADDRINFO  
+HAVE_REGCOMP  -USE_GNU_REGEX  
+HAVE_COLOR  +HAVE_START_COLOR  +HAVE_TYPEAHEAD  +HAVE_BKGDSET  
+HAVE_CURS_SET  +HAVE_META  +HAVE_RESIZETERM  
+CRYPT_BACKEND_CLASSIC_PGP  +CRYPT_BACKEND_CLASSIC_SMIME  -CRYPT_BACKEND_GPGME  
-EXACT_ADDRESS  -SUN_ATTACHMENT  
+ENABLE_NLS  -LOCALES_HACK  +HAVE_WC_FUNCS  +HAVE_LANGINFO_CODESET  +HAVE_LANGINFO_YESEXPR  
+HAVE_ICONV  -ICONV_NONTRANS  +HAVE_LIBIDN  +HAVE_GETSID  -USE_HCACHE  
-ISPELL
SENDMAIL="/usr/sbin/sendmail"
MAILPATH="/var/mail"
PKGDATADIR="/opt/local/share/mutt"
SYSCONFDIR="/opt/local/etc"
EXECSHELL="/bin/sh"
-MIXMASTER
To contact the developers, please mail to <mutt-dev@mutt.org>.
To report a bug, please visit http://bugs.mutt.org/.
```

As it stands, it is not configured to use smtp, but imap should be enabled. However, just starting mutt hangs on

```
Connecting to gmail.com...
```

Is there a way to check the logs or something to see if, say it can't find the server or the password is being rejected or something else?

**Update:**

After installing for ssl, imap, and smtp support, I still get these warnings/errors, even though it can connect to gmail.

```
Error in $HOME/.muttrc line 9: trash: unknown variable
Error in $HOME/.muttrc, line 11: header_cache: unknown variable
```

Comment: Everything worked following that guide with mutt 1.5.21, which is from 2010-09-15. The #! guide shows that setup because it's debian based, and the debian stable repo has 1.5.20

Comment: Thanks, @Rob! I have updated to 1.5.21, and it seems I can't connect to gmail yet.

Comment: Did you set the rest of the file up? Here's my file (sans passwords)  http://sprunge.us/RKdW

Comment: @Rob, thanks! However, it doesn't recognise some of the parameters like trash and header_cache.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First you can check is you mutt support IMAP and SMTP by exec
`mutt -v`

FLAG like `+USE_IMAP` and `+USE_SMTP`

if you want use IMAP  ,in your muttrc must have

```
set imap_user = "YOUR.EMAIL@gmail.com"
set imap_pass = "PASSWORD" 
set folder = "imaps://imap.gmail.com:993"
set spoolfile = "+INBOX"
```

> If I try to send an email, it doesn't work because instead of IMAP, it
>   tries to send email directly from my localhost's mail system

IMAP?
Maybe you wanted is SMTP

```
set smtp_url = "smtp://yourusername@smtp.gmail.com:587/"
set smtp_pass = "yourpassword"
```

or you can install external programs like esmtp or msmtp